# Why is selection sort performing better than insertion AND quick sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have the below algorithms for insertion sort, selection sort and quick sort respectively.  I've run a test sorting an array of 10,000 integers between 0 - 1000 10 times for each algorithm.  The curious thing is that the average for selection sort is significantly lower than both insertion sort AND quick sort.  The averages were 182044.4, 217.9, and 545.4 milliseconds for insertion, selection, and quick sort respectively.  Allowing for the fact that I can likely make small enhancements to insertion and quick sort, I wouldn't expect the lack of those enhancements to result in such large differences.  Where am I wrong in the implementation here?  Again, not small enhancements such as moving indices or checks, but actual errors.

I've provided, the code for the tests and the results below

Thanks

```
public final static <E extends Comparable<E>> ArrayList<E> insertionSort(ArrayList<E> arr)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if(arr.get(j).compareTo(arr.get(j - 1)) < 0)
            {
                swap(arr, j, j-1);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
    return arr;
}
```

`

```
public final static <E extends Comparable<E>> ArrayList<E> selectionSort(ArrayList<E> arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++){
            int min = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++){
                if(arr.get(j).compareTo(arr.get(min)) < 0){
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            swap(arr, i, min);
        }
        return arr;
    }`
```

`

```
public final static <E extends Comparable<E>> ArrayList<E> quickSort(ArrayList<E> arr)
    {
        quickSort(arr, 0, arr.size() -1);
        return arr;
    }
    private static <E extends Comparable<E>> void quickSort(ArrayList<E> arr, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if(hi - lo < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        if((hi - lo) == 1)
        {
            if(arr.get(lo).compareTo(arr.get(hi)) > 0)
            {
                swap(arr, lo, hi);
            }
            return;
        }
        int pivot = (hi - lo) / 2 + lo;
        int j;
        swap(arr, pivot, hi);
        pivot = hi;
        for(int i = lo; i < pivot; i++)
        {
            if(arr.get(i).compareTo(arr.get(pivot)) > 0 )
            {
                for(j = i + 1; j < pivot; j++)
                {
                    if(arr.get(j).compareTo(arr.get(pivot)) < 0)
                    {
                        swap(arr, i, j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(j == pivot)
                {
                    swap(arr, i, pivot);
                    pivot = i;
                }
            }
        }
        //do sort op here
        quickSort(arr, lo, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pivot + 1, hi);
    }
```

`

The code to test - genRans(n) just generates an array list of random numbers between 0 and n
`
        int n = 10000;
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

```
    int tries = 10;
    double[] times = new double[tries];
    double sum = 0;
    double time = 0;
    long startTime = 0;
    long endTime = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
    {
        list = genRans(n);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        //System.out.println("before " + list);
        Sort.selectionSort(list);
        //System.out.println("after" + list);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        time = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000; 
        times[i] = time; 
        sum += time; 
    }

    System.out.println("Times for selection sort = " + Arrays.toString(times));
    System.out.println("Avg time for selection = " + sum / tries);
    sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
    {
        list = genRans(n);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Sort.insertionSort(list);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        time = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000; 
        times[i] = time; 
        sum += time; 
    }

    System.out.println("Times for insertion sort = " + Arrays.toString(times));
    System.out.println("Avg time for insertion = " + sum / tries);
    sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
    {
        list = genRans(n);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Sort.quickSort(list);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        time = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000; 
        times[i] = time; 
        sum += time; 
    }

    System.out.println("Times for quick sort = " + Arrays.toString(times));
    System.out.println("Avg time for quick = " + sum / tries);
}
```

`
Results:
Times for selection sort = [235.0, 214.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 216.0, 217.0, 216.0, 217.0, 216.0]
Avg time for selection = 217.9
Times for insertion sort = [182936.0, 181976.0, 182571.0, 182448.0, 180757.0, 180567.0, 181593.0, 185073.0, 181241.0, 181282.0]
Avg time for insertion = 182044.4
Times for quick sort = [629.0, 487.0, 579.0, 557.0, 547.0, 482.0, 543.0, 571.0, 525.0, 534.0]
Avg time for quick = 545.4

Comment: I guess the issue is how you're measuring the result of your program execution. Let me guess: inside `main`, you're calling each sort method one after another.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to test performance.

Comment: Yeah, that isn't going to get you realistic performance numbers for how long those algorithms actually take in practice.

Comment: I've added the output as well.  Is the quality of test so poor to produce those results?

Comment: 10 tries isn't enough for a benchmark by at least six orders of magnitude.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that increasing the # of tests by 6 orders of magnitude would show that quick sort is significantly better given the difference in results now

Comment: @user3442536 Your present results are meaningless. It is therefore futile to extrapolate *anything* from them. You could always try it and prove us wrong. If you want to just argue, try elsewhere.

Comment: I don't wish to argue. I will increase the # of tries.  In the meantime, does anything appear largely incorrect with the algos?

Comment: something is off with those numbers.  Insertion sort really ran for 3 minutes per iteration?  Did the program run for half an hour?  Are you sure you weren't accidentally dividing time difference by a wrong factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quicksort partitioning step is actually quadratic-time, and almost certainly buggy.

When you find an `i` such that `arr[i] > arr[pivot]`, you're currently scanning forward from `i+1` to find a position `j` to swap it with: this will result in the same array elements being skipped over many times.  Suppose that the first n/2 items are initially all `> arr[pivot]`, and the rest are all `< arr[pivot]`: each of the first n/2 iterations of the outer loop (that increments `i`) will necessitate n/2 iterations of the inner loop that increments `j` to find a partner to swap with, for O(n^2) iterations overall.

Also if you can't find a partner `j` to swap `i` with, you currently swap the pivot into position `i`.  That means that if there are more values above the pivot than below it, the pivot will wind up in the wrong location -- after all values less than it have been exhausted (as partners for swapping with values greater than it), it will keep sliding to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Something is definitely wrong with the way you are measuring time.  I timed your sorting methods (plus java's built-in sort) with JMH.  Here are the results for 10000 elements:

```
Benchmark            Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
SortVSort.insertion  avgt   30  52.802 ± 0.103  ms/op
SortVSort.java       avgt   30   1.196 ± 0.004  ms/op
SortVSort.quick      avgt   30  23.923 ± 0.026  ms/op
SortVSort.selection  avgt   30  99.173 ± 0.105  ms/op
```